# Массивы и foreach

Tags: c#

Скажите, кто может объяснить про использование массивов **простым языком**? А то в книгах какими-то заумными словами объясняют. И ещё, если можно, то тоже **простым языком**, сказать об операторе

```
foreach
```

Comment: Если в книгах слова кажутся заумными, поищите в google видео уроки по C#. Я бы дал ссылку, но боюсь меня забанят. Иногда действительно лучше увидеть, чем часами копаться в книгах.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно MSDN [foreach, in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

> Оператор foreach повторяет группу вложенных операторов для каждого элемента массива или коллекции объектов, реализующих интерфейс System.Collections.IEnumerable или System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T).

На простом примере.

```
// Создаем массив и его инициализируем
string[] fruits = { "apple", "pear", "orange", "mandarin" };

// Проходим подряд по множеству значений массива и присваиваем fruit значение 
// очередного элемента
foreach (string fruit in fruits) {
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```

или

```
// Или пробегаем индексы от 0 до lenth - 1 и выводим значение элемента по индексу
for (int i = 0; i++; i < fruits.length) {
    Console.WriteLine(fruits[i]);
}
```

Comment: >for (int i = 0; i++; i < fruits.length)

 Проверку условия и инкремента местами переставил.

Answer (score 2):

Массив - это непрерывная последовательность элементов указанного типа. Когда создается массив объектов (экземпляров классов) - на самом деле это массив ссылок на них. Поскольку элементы массива одного типа, то все они занимают одинаковое количество байтов, и, благодаря непрерывности, имеется возможность быстрого обращения к элементу массива по его порядковому номеру (в отличие, например, от связных списков).

Оператор foreach позволяет выполнить перебор всех элементов *перечислителя*. Перечислитель - это любой объект, который реализует интерфейс IEnumerable (например, тот же массив). А оператор foreach - просто изящная синтаксическая обертка.
так код

```
foreach x in list
{
  dosmth(x);
}
```

эквивалентен следующему

```
var iterator = list.GetEnumerator();
while (iterator.MoveNext())
  dosmth(iterator.Current);
```

Comment: я думаю стоит отличать массив от коллекции, так как все же массив - это прерывная последовательность, так как есть первый и последний элемент массива, другое дело - коллекция и ее типы

Comment: Под словом "непрерывная" я имел в виду математическое понятие - т.е. в середине массива "дырок" нет, он занимает непрерывный блок памяти. Что такое "коллекция и её типы" я не очень понимаю. Видов коллекций некоторое количество, массив - тоже один из видов. Для каких-то типов коллекций в Framework предусмотрены готовые классы, для каких-то приходится писать свои.

Comment: Поправьтесь 
>>> массив классов
Может объектов, экземпляров,etc?

Comment: Замечания принято.