# Особенность цикла foreach

Tags: c#, алгоритм, циклы, foreach

Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает?

```
foreach (var productModel in productModels)
        {
            foreach (var barCode in productModel.BarCodes)
            {
                if (uniqueBarCodes.Contains(barCode))
                {
                    productModel.BarCodes = productModel.BarCodes.Where(b => b != barCode).ToArray();
                }
             }
        }
```

Почему изменяя productModel, меняется и изначальная коллекция?

Comment: А почему не должна меняться?

Comment: Экземпляр коллекции кладется же в новую переменную productModel. Как она связана с изначальной коллекцией?

Comment: вот читайте тут о `foreach` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/53470/194837

Comment: с чего вы взяли, что это новая переменная?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет или не будет изменяться объект в коллекции productModels зависит от того, каким типом является ее элемент: ссылочным или значимым, если первым, то в переменную productModel попадает только ссылка на элемент, в коллекции также хранится только ссылка (это, по сути, указатель на область памяти, где хранится сам объект), естественно, что в этом случае Вы просто меняете объект, находящийся по ссылке. Если же тип значимый, то в productModel попадет копия объекта, тогда элемент коллекции productModels изменяться не будет.
Изучите систему типов .NET, тогда таких вопросов у Вас не будет.

Про типы можно почитать здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/

Про ссылочные типы: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

Также, есть две неплохих статьи на Хабре: 
https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/68552/
https://habrahabr.ru/post/113586/